# Python3 what for i in range(nums.count(val)): does

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am breaking down the following problem:

```
def removeElement(nums, val):
    for i in range(nums.count(val)):
        nums.remove(val)
        return len(nums)
```

I cannot understand what `for i in range(nums.count(val)):` does

Thx

Comment: There are tutorials for that. [ask]

Comment: Not what it's supposed to do, that's for sure...

Comment: @Shadow You mean that line, or the function as a whole?

Comment: @Shadow (It sounds like the line, since that's the "it" they're talking about, but that line looks like it *is* doing what it's supposed to. The only incorrect thing I see is the too far indented return...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nums.count(val)` counts how many instances of `val` are in `nums`.

`for i in range(nums.count(val)):...` is a loop that iterates `nums.count(val)` times, or, in other words, it iterates as many times as the number of `val`'s in `nums`.

`i` does not actually do anything here, so the more "Pythonic" way of writing that would be to replace `i` with an underscore (`_`) to indicate that the variable is not used.

Finally, `nums.remove(val)` removes the first occurence of `val` from `nums`. This is repeated `num.count(val)` times, so this loop is actually removing all instances of `val` from `num`.

`return len(nums)` simply returns the number of elements in `nums` after all the `val`'s are removed, though it is wrongly indented (should be outside of the `for` loop).